# what is dynamic programming approach for this version of minimum edit distance?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is a dynamic programming approach for minimum edit distance, you can check it:[here](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Dynamic/Edit/)

in it we are allowed to insert,delete or change a character to covert s1 to s2.But in this problem we are allowed to insert,delete or DISPLACE any character of s1 to convert it to s2.Each of these operations have W1,W2,W3 cost respectively.For example to convert "more" to "remo" only we need to displacement of "r<->m" and "o<->e" so cost is 2*w3
we want a dynamic programming approach to find the minimum cost of converting s1 to s2 with these three operations.

Comment: and what are your thoughts?

Comment: i think this is an NPC problem but i can't prove it